Traveling to the Schengen area after visiting North Cyprus
I would like to travel to Sweden but I have got passport entry and exit stamped at Ercan Airport in Northern Cyprus. I have Turkish passport. Is it possible to apply any Schengen country visa, will stamp affect my Schengen visa?
